# How many different arrangements of seating can my friends and I sit at the movies?

Tags: permutations, combinations

Myself and 6 of my friends (1,2,3,4,5 and 6) have organised to see a movie. I am about to give the seat tickets out to my friends. However my friends have a complex relationship with each other. 1 hates 3, and will not sit with him at all. 5 has a medical condition, and must be seated at the end. 4 and 6 are in a relationship, and will only sit together, whereas 2 wants to sit next to me. How many different arrangements of seating are possible?

Comment: Try yourself first..

Comment: How far did you get?  Treat the pairs that must sit together (4 and 6, yourself and 2) as an "item", subject to the possibility of left-right switching.

Comment: I tried factorials,

Comment: This looks like a Graph Coloration problem.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote whether to reopen it or leave it closed. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will follow almagest's lead and call you person $7$.  As it is a bit awkward to place people in boxes, let's solve the equivalent problem of arranging the numbers $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$ in a row so that $5$ is at the end of the row, $1$ is not adjacent to $3$, $2$ is adjacent to $7$, and $4$ is adjacent to $6$.

We will place the $5$ last.

Place the numbers $2$ and $7$ in a blue box and the numbers $4$ and $6$ in a red box.  There are $2!$ ways of arranging the two boxes.  The numbers within each box can be arranged internally in $2!$ ways.

Since $1$ and $3$ cannot be adjacent, they must be separated by the boxes.  Now that the boxes are in place, we have three spaces in which to place the $1$, to the left of both boxes, between them, or to the right of both boxes.  Once we have placed the $1$, we are left with two spaces in which to place the $3$.

Finally, we place the $5$ at the left end or right end of the row.

Consequently, the number of possible arrangements is 
$$2! \cdot 2! \cdot 2! \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 = 96$$

Answer (score 0):

Call yourself 7, you need to order 27,46,1,3,5 so that 5 is first or last and 1,3 are not adjacent.

There are two ways of placing 5. Then there are 3 ways of picking the places for 1,3:

x o o x, x o x o, o x o x (where x = 1/3, o = other)

Then 2 ways of placing 1,3 in those slots.

That leaves two slots for 27,46. Then you have 2 orders for 27 (27 or 72) and 2 for 46. So total $2\times3\times2\times2\times2\times2=96$.